# Where i have to add code to get instagram photos in home page in porto theme in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I want to display `Instagram photos` in my home page but problem is I don't know where I have to place code...
Could you please let me know where I have to place the code ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: https://magecomp.com/magento-2-instagram-integration.html with Facebook Graph API

Comment: solutions for instagram photos with [Magento 2 Instagram Integration](https://www.mageants.com/instagram-integration-for-magento-2.html) extension

Answer (score 4):

First you should install **Instagram Widget – Magento 2 Extension**

Installation Process

Note: Please take a backup of your all Magento files and database before installing or updating any extension.

Download the extension file:

1. Download the Instagram Widget extension .ZIP file from solwininfotech.com using your Solwin Infotech website account.
2. Extract the .ZIP file which contains another .ZIP files.
3. Now, you will see the extension .ZIP file for Magento 2.0.x, Magento 2.1.x, 
   Magento 2.2.x and Magento 2.3.x version.

Extension Installation:

1. If you are using Magento 2.0.x then you need to extract solwin-instagram-m2- 
   2.0.x.zip file.

   If you are using Magento 2.1.x then you need to extract solwin-instagram-m2-2.1.x.zip file.

   If you are using Magento 2.2.x then you need to extract solwin-instagram-m2- 
   2.2.x.zip file.

   If you are using Magento 2.3.x then you need to extract solwin-instagram-m2- 
   2.3.x.zip file.
2. Copy the app folder and paste it into your magento ROOT directory.
3. Run upgrade command as specified : php bin/magento setup:upgrade
4. Run deploy command as specified : php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
5. Clear the cache either from the admin panel or command line : php bin/magento cache:clean
6. Now, you can see the Solwin menu in admin panel. Please go to Solwin -> Instagram Widget -> Configuration and select Enable to Yes.
7. Change/Set all other options as per your requirements and save settings.

**NOTE :** Make sure the installation is done from under the FTP administrator account. Otherwise make sure to set 775 permissions to the store root directory after the extension is deployed.

**Information :**

Instagram Widget Magento 2 extension is an effective way to integrate Instagram with Magento 2 store. There is no any in-built feature in Magento for integration and display an Instagram feed. So, we have designed Instagram Widget Extension to equip this service on your store.

This extension will boost your products and helps you gain more customers to your store. At present, Instagram feed is a must-have for a successful online store. This will avail you to add new products by just taking photos of it. You can create gallery of your Instagram photos with a special tags.

Magento 2 Instagram Integration Extension will improve your store functionality. There is no Instagram authorization or permissions reviews are required to integrate. This is a powerful widget to take your customers to a new level.

[image: step 1]

[image: step 2]

[image: step 3]

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use below example code.

```
{{block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="instagram" padding_item="10px" template="Smartwave_SocialFeed::instagramphotos.phtml"}}
```

Besides, you can config the Instagram Feed on Homepage by going to Admin Panel > Smartwave > SW EXTENSION > Social Feeds > Instagram

To get the Instagram Feed works, you need to insert the right AccessToken and UserID of your Instagram account. 
Ahout how to get those info, please follow this guide.

Comment: Where i have to place above code ?

Comment: if in case you want to show blog posts only from specific blog category you can use category_id tag e.g:
{{block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="instagram" padding_item="10px" template="Smartwave_SocialFeed::instagramphotos.phtml"}}

Comment: i have show in my home page so where i have to place this code ?